# Bad gateway error with Nginx load balancing?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have three servers, my primary server, my secondary server, and my load balancer. I am using Nginx as my load balancer but I getting a bad gateway error.

On the load balancer in my Nginx site config file, I have:

```
upstream backend {
        server 1.1.1.1:80;
        server 1.1.1.2:80;
}
```

In my server block, I have:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

In my nginx error log I am getting "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream"

When I go to my load balancers IP, 1.1.1.3, I receive a bad gateway error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your Nginx config, assuming the addresses are correct.

Comment: What would it have to do with? I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary in my access/error logs on my primary server?

Comment: Why would you?  You're not getting connected to it.  If you do a `curl` or equivalent from the proxy box to one of those backends, you should see it fail.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a couple of params

Your upstream is missing keepalive

```
    server 1.1.1.1:80;
    server 1.1.1.2:80;
    keepalive 64;
```

Try adding these this

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
proxy_set_header        Host                    $http_host;
proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy           true;
proxy_set_header        Connection "";
proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_cache_key         sfs$request_uri$scheme;
proxy_pass              http://backend;
```